# Бесконечный цикл в Java

Tags: java

```
int a = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println();
        int b = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println();
        int c = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println();
        for (int i = c; a < b; i = i + c ) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
```

Использую свои числа, но при любом раскладе код выдаёт бесконечный цикл.

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю java, но если я правильно понимаю логику, условие выхода из цикла у вас `a < b`, и оно с каждой новой итерацией не изменяется, отсюда бесконечный цикл, `a` всегда меньше `b`